# Objective C Separate Class for KB Management

Tags: objective-c, ios, class

I am trying to create a generalized class for managing my keyboard and adding a toolbar to that keyboard. I have several ViewControllers that will be accessing this class. This class will have several methods, one of which will be `addToolbar`.

Let's do a small example here:

When my `MainViewController` loads, it will call `viewDidLoad`. Normally on `viewDidLoad` it will have to create a new toolbar and add it to each text field by calling `setInputAccessoryView:`. What I want to do is just call a separate class (our keyboard manager), but that keyboard manager will need to be able to access the `MainViewController`'s text fields and be able to call `setInputAccessoryView` on them.

Is this possible? If so, how can I get started with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `MainViewController` loads, calling `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    keyboard = [[KeyboardScroll alloc]init];
    //we send the text fields to get a tool bar IN ORDER on the view
    NSArray *textFieldArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ccNum, nameOnCard, expMo, expYr, cvv, zip, nickName, pin, nil];
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [keyboard kbToolbarAndNotifReg:textFieldArray];
    for (int i=0;i<[textFieldArray count];i++)
    {
        [[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:i]setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
    }
}
```

and the `UIToolbar *toolbar = [keyboard kbToolbarAndNotifReg:textFieldArray];` is where the real stuff lies. It registers for notifications for scrolling the scrollView (not completed yet), then the `keyboard` saves the `textFieldArray` for future use, and it also creates a toolbar to go on top of the keyboard and returns it. I then loop around and `setInputAccessoryView:toolbar` in the `MainViewController`.

When the text field is tapped, a notification is called (one of the notifications we registered for earlier in `keyboard`),  and calls a local method inside `keyboard` that has the array information we need. I am still working on completing this, but so far it's coming along nicely.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a formal [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html), `KeyboardToolbarClient` or something, having a required method that exposes all of the interface items to which the toolbar should be added? The protocol could also have an associated notification and a method for posting that notification; view controllers which adopt the protocol would post when they appear, letting the manager know it's time to act.

Any view controller that you want to have this functionality then implements the protocol; when it appears your keyboard manager object asks the view controller for the list and can do whatever it needs through the supplied pointers.

```
// KeyboardToolbarClient.h

@protocol KeyboardToolbarClient <NSObject>

- (NSArray *) interfaceItemsNeedingToolbar;

- (void) postDidAppearNotification;

@end

NSString * KTCViewControllerDidAppear = @"KTCViewControllerDidAppear";
```

Each view controller adopts `KeyboardToolbarClient`:

```
#import "KeyboardToolbarClient.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <KeyboardToolbarClient>

// etc.

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (NSArray *) interfaceItemsNeedingToolbar {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects: textField1, textField2, 
                                      textField3, nil];
}

- (void) postDidAppearNotification {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:KTCViewControllerDidAppear 
                                                        object:self 
                                                      userInfo:nil];
}

// etc.
```

This might even be over-complicated. Depending on how you're accessing the keyboard manager from the view controllers (presumably the manager is a singleton?), you could simply have a method on the manager to which you pass all the interesting interface objects.

Comment: Working on this now, thanks for the help. I'll keep everyone posted.

Comment: I guess, from your accept of my answer, that you ended up using my idea. I just compiled this by brain, and I'd be interested to see your exact code, if you don't mind posting it as a separate answer.

Comment: I used a spin off for the separate class that works. I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider subclassing UITextField instead. Then each instance of your custom UITextField will know how to adorn itself (through methods you define in your subsclass). In your view controllers that use your custom text field, you can call these custom methods in `viewDidLoad:` or where ever it makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to subclass UITextField to ask your view controller for the input accessory view.  Give your MainViewController a property `globalInputAccessoryView` that you set to your common input accessory view.  In your UITextField subclass, do this:

#### `MyTextField.m`

```
- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView
{
    // Search up the responder chain to find something
    // (presumably MainViewController)
    // that has an input accessory view for me to use.

    UIResponder *responder = [self nextResponder];
    UIView *view = nil;
    for ( ; responder && !view; responder = [responder nextResponder]) {
        if ([responder respondsToSelector:@selector(globalInputAccessoryView)])
            view = [(id)responder globalInputAccessoryView];
    }

    return view;
}
```